# Can a parameter have value from different datasets SSRS report builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have 4 datasets in my **reportbuilder 3.0:**

- Binder
- Cedent
- Insured
- Reinsurer

Instead of creating 4 parameters for each dataset, I want to create 2 parameters as follows:

1. **"Generate By"** with values are set manually " "Binder", "Cedent", "Insured", "Reinsured".
2. **"Second Field"** will have its values based on the value set in **"Genereate By"**:

   - If I select **"Binder"** the second field should have values from **Binder dataset**.
   - If I select **"Cedent"** the second field should have values from **Cedent Dataset**.
   - etc.

Can any one assist please?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and tell us what the specific problems with your approach(es) are? Note that you can edit your question to add details at any time (which even bumps your question, if it's substantial).

Comment: What stops you from creating a combined dataset with the values from Binder/Cedent/Insured/Reinsurer: `SELECT value FROM Binder WHERE 'Binder' = @GenerateBy UNION ALL ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because the only way to put dataset values in a parameter is to check the option "get values from a dataset" (When you set a new parameter) and in this section you must select a dataset.

If it was possible to do that you would have to set the values of the parameter from a field in a dataset, but when you try to do that report builder would give you an error

[image]

What is your goal? what are trying to achieve?

maybe there are different ways yo accomplished it

Comment: My goal is tho make my report run faster; i could just add 4 parameters for each of Binder/Cedent/Insured/Reinsurer, and check the option "Allow Multiple value" for each, if each time users want to generate the report it will apply the filter for the each of the 4 which will slow my report, i want the report to filter only one of the 4 parameters.
I cant write a normal select query because i dont have access to database fields, i choose my reports fields from modules with a specific fields <SemanticQuery xmlns="http:/.....

Comment: also ive tried the following: in dataset filter i added the below filter: OR(FIND(<<field name>>,<<param name>>) <> 0, <<param name>> = EMPTY), AND I checked the option Allow Null value, and it works very well, report will skip this filter if null is checked, however it will allow me to choose from a list if null is not check, the field becomes a textbox, and if i choose available values from a dataset, the null checkbox disappear. any ideas??